# How do you convert a frequency table to a list in r

Tags: r

I have a table of values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
3 9 3 1 4 8
```

etc... where the first row is the observation and the second row is the number of observations. How do I reverse this table() into a list of c(1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2) etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rep` :

```
tab <- table(mtcars$cyl)

# 4  6  8 
#11  7 14 

rep(names(tab), tab)

#[1] "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "8"
#[20] "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8"
```